# Mouse event[X and Y coordinates]

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new to electron and somehow my JS script is not working in electron.
Here is my Javascript .I would like to implement this code in electron by making it a desktop application. Kindly help me. Whenever I tried starting it using electron I can't seem to have the results like in a web browser.

Here I provide the JS script and the HTML.

```js
var numbers = [];
var Globaldistance;
$(function() {
  var x1,y1,x2,y2; 
  var drawlines ;
  var theCanvas = document.getElementById('paint');
  var ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = document.getElementById("trya"); 
  theCanvas.width = 500;
  theCanvas.height = 500;

  var canvasOffset = $('#paint').offset();
  $('#paint').mousemove(function(e) {
    if (drawlines) {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,theCanvas.width,theCanvas.height);
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.beginPath();
    
      ctx.moveTo(drawlines.x, drawlines.y);
      ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
      ctx.stroke(); 
    
   document.getElementById("hehe").innerHTML= "Page X2: "+e.pageX;
   document.getElementById("haha").innerHTML= "Page Y2: "+e.pageY;
   x2 = e.pageX; 
   y2 = e.pageY; 
  
    }   numbers.push(x1,y1);
      numbers.push(x2,y2);
   document.getElementById("tra").innerHTML= "Coordinates in x1 y1 x2 y2 respectively : "+numbers[0]+" "+numbers[1]+" "+numbers[2]+" "+numbers[3]; 
   compute(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3]);
  });

  $('#paint').mousedown(function(e) {
    drawlines = {
      x:e.pageX - canvasOffset.left,
      y:e.pageY - canvasOffset.top
  
      }
   document.getElementById("hihi").innerHTML= "Page X1: "+e.pageX;
   document.getElementById("hoho").innerHTML= "Page Y1: "+e.pageY; 
   x1= e.pageX;
   y1= e.pageY;

  });

  $(window).mouseup(function() {
    drawlines = null;
 numbers = [];  
  });
});
function compute(a,b,c,d){
 var x2x1 = c - a;
 var y2y1 = d - b;
 var dist = Math.sqrt(x2x1 * x2x1 + y2y1 *y2y1);
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= Math.round(dist);
 Globaldistance = dist;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="can">
 <canvas id="paint" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
 </div>
 <p id="hehe"></p>
 <p id="haha"></p>
 <p id="hihi"></p>
 <p id="hoho"></p>
 <p id="tra"></p>
 <p id="test"></p>  
 <script src="measure.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```